# Choosing local storage to store music files in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a flutter application that allows the user to provide a YouTube video link and download music file of this video and save it in local storage, then in future he can open the music file from local storage, the app also can track the progress, so the user in the next time when he opens the app and open specific music it starts from the last minute he listened for last time.

I don't know which local storage package can I use for storing the music files, and also to store progress data.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) package.

Here's just a demonstrative example:

```dart
Future<dynamic> downloadFile(String url) async {
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
  var bytes = await getBytesFromLinkYoutube(url);
  await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  print(file.path);
}

Future getBytesFromLinkYoutube(String url) {
  //...
}
```